# How to create config and call in endpoint using ApiClusterJS?

Tags: javascript, endpoint, apicluster

I'm using `ApiClusterJS` and below is my endpoints, i want to have the `user` to be configurable.

http://www.example.com/api/user/list
http://www.example.com/api/user/add/{id}
http://www.example.com/api/user/remove/{id}
http://www.example.com/api/user/update/{id}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem can be solved easily in `ApiClusterJS`.

#### Configuration Part

```
ApiCluster
  .defaults({
    name: 'mydefault',

    config: {
      'user': 'api/user'
    },

    endpoints: {
      "userList": "_user_/list",
      "addUser": "_user_/add/:userId",
      "removeUser": "_user_/remove/:userId",
      "updateUser": "_user_/update/:userId"
    }
  });
```

#### Return User List Endpoint URL.

```
  var userListURL = ApiCluster.get('userList').url();
  document.write( addUserURL );
```

#### Return Add User Endpoint URL.

```
  var addUserURL = ApiCluster
      .get('addUser')
      .arg({
        'userId': 342543
      })
      .url();

   document.write( addUserURL );
```